# Bluetooth-LE GATT write results in notification with same data using RN4020 MLDP protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I wonder if anyone else is seeing this.  We have successfully used the RN4020 MLDP protocol (similar intent to SPP on Classic Bluetooth) with both iOS and a Bluetooth-LE USB module (BLED112) on Windows.  Basically serial bytes coming in to the RN4020 module are sent via a characteristic, resulting in a notification on the connected device (iPhone, PC).  Bytes written to the characteristic on the connected device come out of the RN4020 serial port.

But using similar API calls on Android (using C#/Xamarin low-level APIs),  I occaisionally see the data I send appear as a notification.  About 1 time in 5.  The data sent does go to the module and then to the equipment it is attached to.  I think I saw evidence that there was some sensitivity to timing.

Has anyone seen similar behavior?   I do not see this on iOS or the BluetoothLED dongle (BLED112).  I believe too that the Windows UWP version I started did not show this behavior.

Thanks to anyone who can help me understand this -- currently I have a hack in to discard received data that exactly matches what was sent out recently.  But I would hate to release like this.